# Session variables in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, session-variables

How to get sessions variables in iOS. For example I had five view controllers starting from login page. When logged in as a user I was able to get user id from my JSON data. I want this user id to be used in all the screens to get it done in a smoother way. What I did is taking a hidden variable and sending it to the next screen which is a tough thing when we have 100 screens. Is there any other way to set the session variables and access those all over the application?

What I had tried is keeping that NSString in Appdelegate but I was not able to uderstand how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save your value in NSUserDefaults and also fetch it from that

for save:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:STRING_OBJECT_OF_YOUR_JSON_LOGIN_ID forKey:@"UserLoginIdSession"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

for retrive:

```
NSString *str = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"UserLoginIdSession"];
```

and when user log out from your app set this to @""

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey:@"UserLoginIdSession"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: DharaParekh where do I need to place this NSUserDefaults and NSString?

Comment: save where you get user id from my JSON data and retrieve it in other 5 controls

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a fancy class/singleton/NSUserdefaults to do this: Heres Why.

- Session variables need to be anything.
- The class itself does not need to maintain state
- `NSUserDefaults` are not a session, they are persisted between app launches.

All you really need is a static class which has a `NSMutableDictionary` in it.

```
// Session.h

@interface Session : NSObject
+ (NSMutableDictionary *) sessionVariables;
@end

// Session.m
#import "Session.h"

static NSMutableDictionary *_session;
@interface Session

+ (NSMutableDictionary *) sessionVariables {
    if (!_session) {
        _session = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }

    return _session;

}
```

So in every class you want session available all you need to do is import `Session.h`
and use the class like this `[Session sessionVariables] setObject:@"something" forKey:@"someKey"]`

and to get things out `id someValue =`[Session sessionVariables][@"something"];`

**The one thing I do recommend is please DO NOT store user/password/sensitive data in any of the answers provided (Including mine), use the [iOS Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html) for that.**

Comment: "SessionOrRAMUserDefaults", I think better name for that class ;)

Comment: @gaussblurinc well, yeah it is :P

Comment: It is better to make `+ (NSMutableDictionary *) sessionVariables` thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

You have lot of choices.

1. Save to `NSUserDefaults`

   ```
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"12345" forKey:@"SessionKey"]; // Save session id

   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"SessionKey"];//Access in other view controllers
   ```
2. Keep it AppDelegate as a property, you can access `AppDelegate` in all the view controllers
3. Create a shared `singleton class` to share the data across multiple view controllers.

Comment: Anil thanks for your response could you please guide me step by step or prove an example so that I can go ahead..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep that information in AppDelegate you only have to create properties in that class (AppDelegate) declared in AppDelegate.h. You can access the appDelegate and its properties from any other part of the app:

```
sessionData = [(MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] sessionProperty];
```

I use to define a macro to avoid that verbosity. In AppDelegate.h :

```
#define  myAppDelegate    ( (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] )
```

So I can access its methods from anywhere in the app:

```
sessionData = myAppDelegate.sessionProperty ;
```

Nevertheless, keeping session data in app delegate is not always a good practice. I much prefer to use a singleton to keep session info. For example:

```
sessionData = [[SessionManager sharedManager] sessionProperty] ;
```

To create a singleton, you only have to create a new class and redefine alloc and copy. And, obviously, define the method sharedManager.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Obviously you are parametrizing every view controller with the userID. Nothing is wrong with doing so and it keeps information encapsulated in a good way. Yes, this can be additional work. Yes, encapsulating data in a good way is additional work.

However, if you want to change it, it is one way to have a property of the application delegate. Keep in mind: This creates a dependency of every class that uses the userID to the application delegate. This reduces the ability of code reuse. Therefore it is a good idea to have an additional class `Session`. Create one at the login process and store it in the application delegate.

The whole process:

A. Create a class `Session`

```
@interface Session : NSObject
@property (readonly, copy) NSString *userID;
@end

@interface Session()
@property (readwrite,copy) NSString *userID;
@end

@implementation Session
- (id)initWithUserID:(NSString*)userID
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self)
  {
    self.userID = userID;
  }
  return self;
}
@end
```

B. Create an instance and store it in the application delegate

```
…
// login 
NSString *userID = …;
self.session = [[Session alloc] initWithUserID:userID];
…
```

C. Using the user ID

To use that you have to import the headers of your application delegate class and the session class:

```
//
#import "AppDelegate.h" // To get the session instance
#import "Session.h"     // To get the user ID

…
Session *currentSession = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.session;
NSString* userID = currentSession.userID;
…
```

You can get rid of the dependency to AppDelegate, if you implement a shared instance of `Session`. Doing so the code be a little bit more straight forward:

```
//
#import "Session.h"     // To get the user ID

…
Session *currentSession = [Session currentSession];
NSString* userID = currentSession.userID;
…
```

How to create such a shared instance (called singleton, even it is not) is explained on SO in many, many answers.